# Interactive chart visualization with website integration

Tags: data-visualization, microsoft-excel

I'm looking for a tool or some kind of framework which lets me visualize Excel data interactively on a website. (independent of the user device if possible)

I should be able to see the values when hovering over with the mouse, change the x/y axis dynamically and zoom in/out.

In the best case the chart creation should work with little to no programming experience and no babysitting by a developer (except for the website implementation). The tool www.piktochart.com has great and easy features but doesn't fit this task .

On the other hand www.chartjs.org seems to be a little too complex for a non-developer, therefore some middle-ground would be needed. Maybe some kind of javascript generator tool?

Comment: For data only, anything which handles [Comma Spirited Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), which Excel can export.  If your Excel sheet ahs formulae, things get complicated

Comment: "The tool www.piktochart.com has great and easy features but doesn't fit this task" ... but you are not going to tell us what & how doesn't fit? If only people would read [ask], we would be better able to help them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/) which has multiple APIs including upload of [excel spreadsheets](http://help.plot.ly/excel/).

- There are multiple pricing plans including a free tier.
- You can share your resulting charts with URL such as [here](https://plot.ly/~SteveBarnes/0/trace0-vs-trace1/) where you can see the features that you mention.
- Download as image files:
  [image]
- Dozens of chart types.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.